# Regex for Upper Case Number and 2 special characters

Tags: java, regex

I would need a Regex which allows only uppercase letters, number and two special characters.

so far I have the Regex for the letters and numbers.

```
^[A-Z0-9]+$
```

I would also like to allow the usage of the "-" and "#" symbols

like 
A453#
A-59#
for example

Any advices?
Cheers

Comment: Shall number *start with a letter* or not? E.g. if "12345" or "#####" are allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^[A-Z0-9#-]+$
```

This should do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Often numbers must *start form a letter* (e.g. `"A1234-5"` is *allowed* when `"###"` is *ruled out*), if it's your case, the pattern is

```
^[A-Z][A-Z0-9#-]*$
```